# I need exact value but my integer variable overflows

Tags: c#, integer-arithmetic

I need to do divide the number which equals to sum of some big values. But after a while, it overflows and it equals to a negative number. I tried to use BigInteger,decimal and double but it doesn't work again.

Error message:System.ArgumentException 'Value of '256' is not valid for 'red'. 'red' should be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 255.'

Edit: When i checked value of GaussFiltresi[syc] i have seen that :'GaussFiltresi[syc]' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

```
#region Gaussian Filter

public void gaussianfilter (int SablonBoyutu,Bitmap GirisResmi,Bitmap CikisResmi)
{
int ResimGenisligi = GirisResmi.Width;
int ResimYuksekligi = GirisResmi.Height;
int syc = 0;
BigInteger toplamR;
BigInteger filtrekatsayitoplami; 
BigInteger ortalamaR;
int kernelsinir = ((SablonBoyutu - 1) / 2); 
for ( i = -kernelsinir; i <= kernelsinir; i++)
{
 for ( j = -kernelsinir; j <= kernelsinir; j++)
  {
  //some calculations
  }
}

for (int x = (kernelsinir); x < ResimGenisligi - kernelsinir; x++)
{
 for (int z = (kernelsinir); z < ResimGenisligi - kernelsinir; z++)
 {
  syc = 0;
  toplamR = 0;
  for (int y = -(kernelsinir); y <= kernelsinir; y++) 
   {
    for (int d = -(kernelsinir); d <= kernelsinir; d++)
    {
    OkunanRenk = GirisResmi.GetPixel(x + y, d + z);
    toplamR += GaussFiltresi[syc] * (BigInteger)(OkunanRenk.R);
    //toplam R=1662424090 and GaussFiltresi[syc] = 5389698 before overflowing
     syc++;
    }
   }
ortalamaR = toplamR / filtrekatsayitoplami; //toplamR is negative 
CikisResmi.SetPixel(x, z, Color.FromArgb((int)ortalamaR, (int)ortalamaR,(int)ortalamaR));
  }
 }
}

        #endregion
```

Comment: Maybe BigInteger can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Please elaborate on "I tried to use Int64 but it doesn't work again.", since division would normally produce a remainder and decimal might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a reference to `System.Numerics.dll`, you can use [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) instead of `Int64` (a.k.a. `long`).

Another option is to use `double` that does not overflow (to `PositiveInfinity`) before `10**308`, or `1e+308`. Or `decimal` that goes to more than `1e+28m`.

Update after comments: Your expression:

```
GaussFiltresi[syc] * OkunanRenk.R
```

is an `int` times an `int`. In fact becomes `14650719 * 160`, which gives `-1950852256`. To have the two operands promoted to `BigInteger`, such that the multiplication `*` will be multiplication of big-ints (that never overflow), cast either operand to `BigInteger` (the other will be promoted to `BigInteger` for free), just as I said in my comment:

```
GaussFiltresi[syc] * (BigInteger)(OkunanRenk.R)
```

so the entire statement becomes:

```
toplamR += GaussFiltresi[syc] * (BigInteger)(OkunanRenk.R);
```

A multiplication of an `int` by an `int` will be done as an `int` multiplication (and the result may "wrap around"). It is not changed by the fact that the result is going to be `+=`-ed to a `BigInteger` later. That was the reason why it did not work after your initial code changes.

Comment: @TylerMiles Be more specific. What exactly did you try? What does that overflowing look like to you? Is it an exception? If yes, what is the message and stack trace? Do you get to negative numbers? None of `BigInteger`, `double` or `decimal` will wrap from a huge positive number to a negative number in the way `int` and `long` do. For a `BigInteger`, it is hard to believe the true reason is an overflow, since it represents numbers with millions and millions of digits in it (but only integers). I think `BigInteger` represents number up to two gigabytes, that is almost `2**17179869184`.

Comment: My last try is on the question part.  I also replaced BigInteger with double and decimal but they didnt work. toplamR overflows, it equals a negative number. Yes it is an exception. Message:  'Value of' '-1' is not valid for red.red should be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 255.

Comment: We need more info. If `toplamR` is a `BigInteger`, it does not become `-1` because of overflow inside `toplamR` itself. I do not know what the type of `GaussFiltresi[syc]` and `OkunanRenk.R` are. If they are `int`, the multiplication of them gives an `int` that may wrap around. If that is the case, you must fix it there. For example, cast one of the factors to `BigInteger`, as in `toplamR += GaussFiltresi[syc] * (BigInteger)(OkunanRenk.R);`. This is pure guessing. __Addition:__ Tip: Hold your mouse over the symbol `*` in Visual Studio to see what overload of `operator *` is being used.

Comment: OkunanRenk.R is a pixel valıe which equals to 160. And GaussFiltresi[syc] is an integer array. When toplamR becomes negative first time,it equals to 14650719

Comment: @TylerMiles Updated answer above.